# PHP to mysql connection not working even with DBM permisions

Tags: php, mysql

Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'andrewshere'@'website adress hidden for saffty' (using password: YES)

I get this error using this code

```
<?php
$servername = "ip_hidden_for_safty";
$username = "andrewshere";
$password = "also hidden";
$database = "IT_ticketing"; // Replace with your actual database name

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
   
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

it should say connection successful although I have tried both with msqli and dbo and neither allow me to connect I am hosting this all on IIS

Comment: Either the password is wrong, or the user@website doesn't have the necessary grants.

Comment: "both with mysqli and dbo"? Do you mean PDO?

Comment: The connection code is fine, so the problem must be the parameters.

Comment: You are looking the wrong way. Neither iis, pdo or mysqli are issues here. It's only database permissions. Add peprmissions for andrewshere@iis_server_ip